# Variables no declaradas en word 2007

Tags: microsoft-office

Voy a hablar de versiones algo antiguas, pero es lo que hay.

Trabajo a menudo con Word 2003. He mantenido esta versión porque en Word 2007 la estructura de barras de la interfaz de usuario es mucho menos personalizable y no quiero renunciar a mis barras y botones asociados a macros programadas por mi.

Ahora estoy haciendo pruebas a ver cómo va el pasarme por fin a 2007. Para ello he creado una normal.dotm a partir de mi antigua normal.dot. No me preocupa ahora el mencionado tema de las barras (estoy dispuesto a renunciar a parte de la personalización) pero me encuentro con el siguiente problema: aunque asumo que no es la practica más aconsejable, tengo muchas macros en las que utilizo variables que no he declarado. Al ejecutarlas ahora en word 2007, mis macros se detienen, aparece el mensaje <"Error de compilación. No se puede encontrar el proyecto o la biblioteca"> y el intérprete aparece detenido en la línea donde aparece la variable no declarada.

Entonces voy a Editor de VBA - Herramientas - Opciones y deshabilito la opción <"Requerir declaración de variables">. Pero el problema sigue igual. Adelanto que no es una cuestión relativa a que falten Librerías, porque se reproduce con un programa como

```
    Sub prueba ()
    'Dim aaaaadd As String
    aaaaadd = "dfdfd"
    End Sub
```

y además porque si descomento la línea con la declaración el programa corre normalmente sin interrupmirse.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Entonces porque no declaras esas variables? mira tu comentario: dices que si descomentas la linea de la declaracion, el programa corre normalmente... ¿porque no entonces declararlas?

Comment: Gracias TwoDent. Está claro lo que dices. El problema es que como llevo bastantes años con Word 2003, tengo mas de 300 macros, algunas de ellas de una extensión respetable, es decir que para mi sería un suplicio tener que declarar ahora todas las variables. Se supone que inhabilitar la opción <"Requerir declaración de variables"> resuelve esto (en 2003 lo hace). Pero por algún motivo que desconozco, en Word 2007 no me funciona,